How does one export audio from multiple Audacity projects with Python?
I have several aup3 Audacity projects that I'd like to export to aiff format. I tried an Audacity macro, but it seems that they can not be applied to aup3 files. The documentation suggests using Python scripting.
I've been working with an LLM on such a script, but can't get it to work. Here is what I have so far:
import os
import time
import pyaudacity as pa


# Path to the directory containing AUP3 files
aup3_directory = "export" # There is usually a full path here.

# Get all AUP3 files in the directory
aup3_files = [f for f in os.listdir(aup3_directory) if f.endswith('.aup3')]


for aup3_file in aup3_files:
    try:
        full_path = os.path.join(aup3_directory, aup3_file)
        print(f"Opening {aup3_file}...")
        # Instruct Audacity to open the AUP3 file
        pa.do(f'OpenProject2: Filename="{full_path}"')
        
        # Wait for the file to load
        time.sleep(5)
        
        # Generate the export path (same name as AUP3 but with .aiff extension)
        export_path = os.path.splitext(full_path)[0] + ".aiff"
                
        print("Exporting...")
        # Export the project to AIFF format
        pa.do(f'Export2: Filename="{export_path}" NumChannels=2')
        
        # Wait for the export to complete
        time.sleep(5)
        
        print("Closing.")
        # Close the project without saving changes to the original file
        pa.do('Close:')
        
        
        # Wait for the project to close
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Closed.")
        print(f"Successfully processed: {aup3_file}")
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {aup3_file}: {str(e)}")
        continue

print("Processing complete.")

Behavior:

The first file opens, seems to be exported, and closes. The script, however, hangs on the next file.
The exported file has an aiff extension, but is only 54 bytes long and produces no sound. (It should be much larger.)

Remarks:

Audacity is running when I run the script.
mod-script-pipe is enabled.
I'm using Audacity 3.6.4.
I'm on an M1 Mac.

